# SQL type specifier

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hello guys we have problem, not knowing how to add type specifier for date type? We tried to use %% but this doesn't seem to work.

```
    public class OrderDB implements OrderDBIF {
@Override
public Order create(Date date, int totalAmount, String deliveryStatus, Date deliveryDate, int invoiceId, int customerId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO Order (date, totalAmount, deliveryStatus, deliveryDate, invoiceId, customerId) VALUES "
            + "('%%', '%d', '%s', '%%', '%d', '%d')", date, totalAmount, deliveryStatus, deliveryDate, invoiceId, customerId);
    try (Connection conn = DBConnection.getInstance().getDBcon();
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: Dates are inserted using strings (usually `'YYYY-MM-DD'`).  However, you should learn to use parameterized queries.  That way, the parameters take care of the typing from the app to the database.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, you need to make sure your date is in specific format. You need to make sure `deliveryDate` has value in specified format

Comment: This could be a sql injection problem. Use a PreparedStatement to execute query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Order "
    + "(date, totalAmount, deliveryStatus, deliveryDate, invoiceId, customerId) VALUES "
    + "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
try (Connection conn = DBConnection.getInstance().getDBcon();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setDate(1, date);
    ps.setInt(2, totalAmount);
    ps.setString(3, deliveryStatus);
    ps.setDate(4, deliveryDate);
    ps.setInt(5, invoiceId);
    ps.setInt(6, customerId);
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

In addition to taking care of proper escaping for all values in the `INSERT`, a prepared statement also protects you against SQL injection.